# My iOS app broke my iPhones recording capabilities, should I worry?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm a bit of a newbie in iOS programming, and have recently tried out some stuff with AVAudioRecorder and AVAudioPlayer, and happend on some strange bugs.

Basicaly what happened was that my app bugged out so hard it broke my iPhones (iPhone 4) audio-recording capabilities. And I'm not just talking about my app not being able to record anymore, none of the apps I tried, such as "Vocie-memo" and recording a movie using the standard-camera-app, where not able to record audio (video for the camera worked fine) anymore.

The problem can only be resolved by restarting the iPhone.

Since I'm a newbie I don't know a lot about these things and if it happens frequently (One app bugging out causing problems for other apps) or if this is something I should report as a bug to Apple.

It was my understanding that the "sandbox" made sure that even though your app bugged out, this wouldn't affect others, but I may be wrong. So my question is: Does this happen often? should I report it?

((For those interested please ask for more info, but it basicaly has to do with sending prepareToPlay to the player but instead begin recording))

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congratulations! You crashed the process that manages recording on iOS devices. You might want to file a radar in [Apple's ancient bug report system](https://bugreport.apple.com/) detailing what happened, but Apple probably wouldn't let an app that does this onto the app store.

So, in conclusion: You don't really have to worry.

Comment: Thanks Simon, in that case I wont worry.

Comment: @MarcusAgelii No worries, I would think about taking the time to notify Apple though. It shouldn't be possible to crash this process, which makes it a bug in their software...